# Autodesk Forge NETWORK_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Forge API just start returning NETWORK_FILE_NOT_FOUND on Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);

Anyone else with this behaviour?

The folderApi.GetFolderContentsAsync(projectId, folderId) correctly returns all the documentIds, but load retrieves NETWORK_FILE_NOT_FOUND...

Yesterday it was working just fine. No change in BIM360...

Comment: Seems to be related to OTG file format, when switch to SVF in the options, everything when back to normal, Autodesk must be changing OTG server side things...

Comment: Which Viewer version are you using? These are the options you should use with the latest version of the Viewer (should handle both SVF2 and SVF): https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/viewer_basics/initialization/#example

Comment: Yes, I was using old options configuration. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from Adam Nagy in comments:
These are the options you should use with the latest version of the Viewer (should handle both SVF2 and SVF):
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/viewer_basics/initialization/#example

Comment: Sorry, don't know how to close it... is turn up the green check mark as I did?

Comment: Yes, thanks! It's important to close